# Asterisk, How can i play an audio file

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freepbx

Here is  the dial plan

[testInComingCalls]

exten => s,1,Answer

exten => 30953025,1,Dial(SIP/20000,20)

I would like to play an audio file as soon as somebody answered the call (Welcome Message)..

Comment: What does the Asterisk documentation say about that?

Answer (score 1):

In freePBX, these are the steps:

1. Add a system recording (Admin -> System Recordings)
2. Create an Announcement using that recording.  (Application -> Announcements)  Set the "destination after ring" to whatever you want to (probably whatever extension somebody is picking up)
3. Set the announcement as the destination on the appropriate inbound route (Connectivity -> Inbound Routes)

Note that this plays a message regardless of whether somebody picks up the extension.

Don't edit your dialplan directly if you're using freepbx.